# Inheriting the virtual specifier of base class's member function

Tags: c++

The following code is based on the example on page 298 of **C++ Templates: the Complete Guide**. I removed the parts not relevant to my question.

```
class Virtual {
  public:
    virtual void foo() {
    }
};

class Base : private Virtual {
  public:
    void foo() {
       std::cout << "Base::foo()" << '\n';
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void foo() {
       std::cout << "Derived::foo()" << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *p = new Derived;
    p->foo();  // calls Derived::foo()
}
```

I do not understand how the call `p->foo()` ends up calling `Derived::foo`. More concretely, the static type of `p` is `Base*`. `Base::foo` is non-virtual. Now, `Base` privately inherits from 'Virtual', which has its own `foo` and it looks as if `Base::foo` somehow gets the `virtual` specifier from `Virtual::foo`. What is actually going on here?

Comment: `Base::foo` **is** virtual.

Comment: U created an instance of Derived, that's why it calls the method from Derived. Check out OOP inheritance.

Comment: @KerrekSB The question is based on a wrong assumption. This happens to people. Clearing the misconception helped me a lot. Does this deserve a penalty?

Comment: Don't take Stack Overflow personally. Votes reflect the perceived usefulness of a question to future readers, not your value as a human being.

Comment: Thank you, @KerrekSB! Although not strictly professional, this was the most valuable comment I received on Stack Overflow so far.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg: Thanks for saying that, that's nice to hear. Many people find SO abrasive and unfriendly, and I think that often that's because the vote- and comment-based "moderation" system is geared towards increasing the value of the content rather than creating a fun social environment. We sometimes say "SO is not a forum" to allude to that, but it's only natural to be invested personally in an exchange and see responses as personal attacks. Everyone should try to be friendly, though it doesn't always get across like that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `virtual`ness of `foo` is inherited from the base class `Virtual`.

In fact, writing `virtual` in `Derived::foo` will be superfluous and many developers will omit it. You cannot *undo* `virtual`ness once you've marked that function as `virtual` in a base class.

You can force a call of `Base::foo` by writing `p->Base::foo();` but that's an ugly contrivance.

Comment: Two quick notes in regards to "You cannot undo `virtual`ness": 1) You can stop new virtual functions with `final`, and 2) If you change the signature of the function, it will mask the original's virtualness even if you use the same signature as well.